# Kanji for native Japanese concepts: Kun'yomi spanning multiple morphemes

Tags: kanji, etymology, history

There are a few words, which are written with Kanji imported from China, but where the intended native Japanese meaning would prefer a different choice of Kanji. My favourite examples are

> 雷 vs. 神鳴り (cf. 海鳴り)
> 鶏 vs. 庭鳥
> 向日葵 vs. 日回り

Does there already exist a list of these words? If not, can anybody come up with more examples?

Comment: I voted to close because this seems so broad that I doubt an exhaustive list could reasonably be constructed.  I touched on a few examples [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1400/78).  Maybe you should narrow down the scope of your questions to something more concrete.

Comment: @istrasci: I agree that we cannot hope for an exhaustive list, but I do not think that that is a good reason to close the question.  Rather, I think that “we cannot hope for an exhaustive list” (with a reason) is a good answer.  And the reason is already hinted by Dono’s list.

Comment: Seems close enough to something that can be made as a community Wiki. I converted it: feel free to improve question and answer formatting.

Comment: This question has prompted me to find out what a morpheme is, but for us non-linguists, who had to read >50% of this before we understood the question, I would suggest "Japanese compound words taking one kanji （eg 心見る->試みる)"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A few years ago I began to create a list. It is incomplete, but you can build from here.

- 湖 → 水海【みずうみ】
- 京 → 宮処【みやこ】
- 暁【あかとき】 → 明時
- 曙 → 明け仄
- 喉 → 飲門【のみと】
- 銅 → 赤金【あかがね】
- 胡床 → 足座【あぐら】
- 羹 → 熱物【あつもの】
- 鐙 → 足踏み【あぶみ】
- 雷【いかずち】 → 厳【いか】つ霊【ち】
- 泉 → 出【い】づ水【み】
- 営む → 暇無【いとな】む
- 猪【いのしし】 → 猪【い】の獣【しし】, 猪【い】の肉【しし】
- 妹 → 妹【いも】人【うと】 (common *hito* shift)
- 甍 → 苛処【いらか】
- 驢 → 兎馬【うさぎうま】
- 鬣【うながみ】 → 項【うな】髪【がみ】
- 頷く → 項【うな】突【づ】く
- 厩 → 馬屋【うまや】 (Shōgakukan lists both spellings for this reading)
- 狼 → 大神【おおかみ】
- 概 → 大旨【おおむね】
- 公 → 大宅【おおやけ】
- 幼い → 長【おさ】無【な】い
- 一昨日【おとつい】 → 遠【おと】つ日【ひ】
- 弟【おとうと】 → 弟【おと】人【うと】
- 男 → 復【お】と子【こ】 (cf. 復つ)
- 乙女 → 復【お】と女【め】
- 俤 → 面影【おもかげ】
- 赴く → 面向【おもむ】く
- 大蛇【おろち】 → 峰ろ霊
- 蚕【かいこ】 → 飼い蚕【こ】
- 象る → 形【かた】取【ど】る
- 刀 → 片刃【かたな】
- 傾く → 片向【かたむ】く
- 鹿【かのしし】 → 鹿【か】の獣【しし】, 鹿【か】の肉【しし】
- 雷【かみなり】 → 神鳴【かみな】り
- 頑張る → 我【が】に張【は】る (might also be from 眼張る)
- 厠 → 川屋【かわや】
- 碓 → 唐臼【からうす】
- 犂 → 唐鋤【からすき】
- 餉 → 乾【かれ】飯【いい】
- 築【きず】く → 城【き】築【つ】く
- 牙【きば】 → 牙【き】歯【ば】
- 轡 → 口輪【くつわ】
- 果物【くだもの】 → 木だ物 (cf. *kedamono*)
- 獣【けだもの】 → 毛だ物 (cf. *kudamono*)
- 獣 → 毛物【けもの】
- 鉄 → 黒金【くろがね】
- 餔【けこと】 → 食【け】事
- 志 → 心指【こころざ】し
- 試みる → 心見【こころみ】る
- 梢 → 木【こ】末【ずえ】
- 遮る【さえぎる】 < さいぎる < 先【さき】切【き】る
- 杯【さかずき】 → 酒【さか】杯【ずき】 < 酒【さか】杯【づき】
- 魚 → 酒菜【さかな】
- 遡る → 逆【さか】上【のぼ】る
- 幸せ → 仕合【しあわ】せ
- 僕【しもべ】 → 下【しも】部【べ】
- 銀 → 白金【しろがね】
- 黄昏 → 誰【た】そ彼【がれ】
- 戦う → 叩【たた】かう
- 相撲 → 争ふ【すまふ】
- 躓く → 爪【つま】突【づ】く
- 忽ち → 立【た】ち待【ま】ち
- 岐 → 道【ち】股【また】
- 鋼 → 刃金【はがね】
- 東【ひがし】 < ひんがし < ひむかし < 日向風【ひむかし】
- 聖 → 日知【ひじ】り
- 彦 → 日子【ひこ】
- 姫 → 日[女]【め】
- 炎 → 火【ほ】の穂【ほ】
- 鶏 → 庭鳥【にわとり】
- 前 → 目【ま】方【え】 < 目【ま】方【へ】
- 真 → 真言【まこと】 or 真事【まこと】
- 瞬く → 目【ま】叩【たた】く
- 睫 → 目【ま】つ毛【げ】
- 瞼 → 目【ま】蓋【ぶた】
- 眶 → 目【ま】縁【ぶち】
- 蝮 → 真【ま】虫【むし】
- 峰【みね】 → 御[峰]【ね】
- 娶る → 女【め】取【と】る
- 社【やしろ】 → 屋代
- 盥【たらい】 → 手洗い
- 慮る → 思【おもい】計【はか】る
- 巫 → 御子【みこ】
- 黿【あおうみがめ】 → 青【あお】海【うみ】亀【がめ】
- 嫁 → [(呼・弱・良・夜)]【よ】女【め】
- 焔 → 火【ほ】群【むら】
- 叢 → 草【くさ】群【むら】
- 則る → 乗【の】っ取【と】る
- 蝙蝠【こうもり】 → 皮張り
- 扉【とびら】 → 戸片
- 啄木鳥【きつつき】→木突き
- 寿司 → 酸し
- 袂【たもと】 → 手元
- 戦【いくさ】 → 射【いく】矢【さ】 < 射【いく】う矢 (= 矢を射る)
- 七夕【たなばた】 → 棚機 (< 棚機つ女) or 種播 (< 種播祭り)
- 素人 → 白人
- 玄人 → 黒人
- 簪【かんざし】 → 髪挿し
- 瞳【ひとみ】 → 人見
- 政【まつりごと】 → 祭り事
- 袖【そで】 → 衣手
- 眼【まなこ】 → 目な子 (< 目の子)
- 裸【はだか】 → 肌赤
- 礎【いしずえ】 → 石据え
- 如月【きさらぎ】 → [着更着・生更木・気更来]
- 暦【こよみ】 → 日読み
- 経【たていと】 → 縦糸
- 緯【よこいと】 → 横糸
- 舷【ふなばた】 → 船端
- 緒【いとぐち】 → 糸口
- 軛【くびき】 → 首木
- 謀【はかりごと】 → 計り事
- 彩【いろど】る → 色取る
- 幹【みき】 → 身木
- 鍋【なべ】 → 肴瓮 (= 肴【な】を煮る瓮【へ】)
- 蝕【むしば】む → 蟲食む
- 兆【きざし】 → 気差し
- 掌【てのひら】 → 手の平
- 掌【たなごころ】 → 手な心 (< 手の心)
- 辛【かのと】 → 金の弟
- 庚【かのえ】 → 金の兄
- 乙【きのと】 → 木の弟
- 甲【きなえ】 → 木の兄
- 己【つちのと】 → 己の弟
- 戊【つちのえ】 → 土の兄
- 癸【みずのと】 → 水の弟
- 壬【みずのえ】 → 水の兄
- 丁【ひのと】 → 火の弟
- 丙【ひのえ】 → 火の兄
- 艮【うしとら】 → 牛虎
- 巽【たつみ】 → 龍巳
- 坤【ひつじさる】 → 羊猿
- 乾【いぬい】 → 犬猪
- 命【いのち】 → 息の霊
- 蛟【みずち】 → 水づ霊 (< 水つ霊)
- 海神【わたつみ】 → 海つ霊
- 山祗【やまつみ】 → 山つ霊
- 帝【みかど】 → 御門
- 芳【かんば】しい → 香【か】精【んば】しい (< かぐわしい < かくわしい)
- 英【はなぶさ】 → 花房
- 宮【みや】 → 御屋
- 窓 → [目門・間戸]
- 李【すもも】 → 酸桃
- 古【いにしえ】 → 往にし方
- 侍【さむらい】 → 候い (< さぶらふ)
- 時雨【しぐれ】 → 過【し】ぐれ (< すぐる)
- 筆【ふで】 → 文手 (< ふみて)
- 再び → 二度
- 恣【ほしいまま】 → 欲しい儘
- 潔い → 甚【いさ】清【ぎよ】い (< 甚【いた】清【きよ】い)
- 嘯【うそぶ】く → 嘘吹く
- 壽【ことぶき】 → 言【こと】祝【ぶ】く (ことほく)
- 階【きざはし】 → 刻[橋＝階]
- 導く → 道引く
- 醜い → 見憎い
- 宣【のたま】う → 宣【の】賜【たま】う (< のりたまう)
- 自【みずか】ら → 身【み】ず故【から】 (< みつから)
- 橘【たちばな】 → 立ち花
- 鋸【のこぎり】 → 刃【の】歯【こ】切【ぎ】り (< のほぎり < なはぎり)
- 奉【たてまつ】る → 立て祭る
- 麓【ふもと】 → 踏本 (spelling found in 万葉集)
- 邪【よこしま】 → 横しま (接尾の「さ」と接尾の「ま」)
- 省みる → 帰【かえ】り見【み】る
- 昂【たか】ぶる → 高振る
- 砦【とりで】 → 取り出
- 頗【すこぶ】る → 少振る
- 簾【すだれ】 → 簀垂れ
- 碑【いしぶみ】 → 石文
- 蔑【さげす】む → 下げ墨む (< 下げ墨【すみ】)
- 滞【とどこおる】る → 留【とど】凍【こお】る
- 擲【なげう】つ → 投げ打つ
- 惨【みじ】め → 見じ目
- 悉【ことごと】く → 事事く
- 巫・覡【かんなぎ】 → 神【かん】和【な】ぎ (< かむなぎ)
- 雛【ひよこ】 → ひよ子 (= ヒヨヒヨと鳴く[鳥の]子)
- 断【ことわ】る → 言【こと】割【わ】る
- 蘇【よみがえ】る → 黄泉【よみ】帰【がえ】る

Comment: oh wow that is pretty cool. I don't understand the "kunyomi spaning multiple morphemes" though. how does this work? can anyone write a formal transformational rule?

Comment: @taylor, what do you mean by a transformational rule?

Comment: @dainichi just a formal grammar that would, for example, take 湖 as input and output 水海 and so forth for each entry on the list. actually i don't know why  i asked, such a set of rules would be pretty useless. i think the little "->" just reminded me of transforms.

Comment: @taylor, what's not formal about the above rules? If you mean a *complete* grammar, I don't think it's easy to make one. Language evolution and the choice of kanji aren't predictable, these transformations aren't *productive*.

Answer (score 10):

I found these two lists, which I'd like to share:

[単純語のようになっているが元々は複合語だった単語](https://jbbs.shitaraba.net/bbs/read.cgi/study/10958/1299762655/)

and

[複合語起源で、複数の形態素に分けられると考えられる例](https://academy6.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/gengo/1228873581/)

Answer (score 9):

Better title? I guess "Kun'yomi spanning multiple morphemes (which each have kanji of their own)" might be more precise, but better... not sure.

Lots of verbs too.

> 顧みる/省みる vs 返り見る
>   試みる vs 心見る
>   陥る/陥れる vs 落ち入る/落とし入れる
>   弄ぶ vs 持て遊ぶ
>   承る vs 受け賜わる

There are cases where the etymology is unclear, or at least not obvious, too. I'm sure 翻す and 覆す are *something*+返す, but I don't know the etymology of ひる and くつ in these combinations.

Comment: “Kun-yomi spanning multiple morphemes” might not be better as a title, but it is a good description of the question.

Comment: Yes - perhaps "Kun-yomi spanning multiple morphemes（eg 心見る->試みる)" would work as an alternative? I appreciate this list because it is something that often crossed my mind when learning kanji.