# Etymology of 宵【よい】

Tags: etymology

This is a loose follow-up of [my first question here on JLSE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/kanji-for-native-japanese-concepts-kunyomi-spanning-multiple-morphemes). I tried to check [gogen-allguide.com](http://gogen-allguide.com/) and 大辞林, but couldn't find anything definitive. Unfortunately I don't know any other resources for checking etymologies for (native) Japanese words.

So, my question is: What is the etymology of 宵【よい】? My guess would be 夜(よ)日(ひ).

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/25766944?uid=372503961&uid=2&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21103670524981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gogen Allguide](http://gogen-allguide.com/yu/yuube.html) and my dead-tree version of Sh­ōgakukan Kokugo Dai Jiten in JA mention that, in the Heian period and earlier, the terms for "evening, night" were somewhat specific, going in order:

- ゆうべ
  Early evening
- よい
  Late evening, early night: dusk
- よなか
  Night
- あかとき
  Pre-dawn
- あけぼの
  Dawn

I can't find anything definitive at present about the derivation of 宵.  I do note, however, that 夜日 is a separate word in its own right, *yohi*: "night and day, day and night".  So that's probably not the source of 宵.

I do see that the older kana spelling was よひ.  I note also that 夕 *yū* of similar meaning has an older kana spelling of ゆふ.  I wonder then if these two might be cognate, with よひ representing some kind of inflection.  Or, possibly, よひ might be the noun stem form of a hypothetical verb よふ, consisting of 夜 "night" + ふ "suffix indicating iterative or continuous action, or ongoing change".  That said, I can't find evidence of any such verb in my sources to hand.

---

***Update.***

The link to JSTOR that snailboat added above in a comment previously didn't work for me, possibly due to net congestion or server trouble.  I have since read through that paper by J. Marshall Unger, [*New Etymologies for Some Japanese Time-Words*](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/25766944?uid=372503961&uid=2&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21103670524981).  In it, he provides the following theory on page 40 for the derivation of modern 宵{よい}, ancient *yopi* (my additions in [square brackets] for clarity):

> Because free native nouns in Old Japanese could begin with *p* but not *r*, the derivation of *yopi* 'evening twilight' is not as problematic as that of *yoru*, though by no means certain.  It was probably a relatively late reduction of a whole phrase such as **yo pikari* 'night shining', with the same **yo* 'night' morpheme.  According to pJ [proto-Japanese] non-final mid-vowel raising, an ancient compound of the form **yo-pi* would have yielded OJ [Old Japanese] **yupi*, not *yopi*, and OJ *pi* 'sun, day' was not used for 'light'.

I'm not sure what *pJ non-final mid-vowel raising* is beyond the summary provided by Unger (apparently outlined in more detail in a separate paper by Frellesvig and Whitman in 2004), but from the context of Unger's paper, I find myself unconvinced—there are OJ terms that don't seem to exhibit this purported *yo-* > *yu-* shift.  I'm also unconvinced that *pikari* would shorten to just *pi*, given that in all other contexts that I'm aware of, the shortest form is *pika*, though I am certainly open to some other term being the cognate source for the *-pi* in *yopi*.

Comment: I think we used to be notified when an answer to one of our questions was edited. Apparently, this feature was dropped. Anyway, thank you very much for your post, especially for your update. In the article it says "OJ _pi_ '**sun, day**'". Would 夜火 be another option, then?

Comment: @Earthliŋ, Footnote 10 on page 40 of the article notes *OJ *pwi* 'fire; light' is a B-type* [i.e. 乙類] *syllable*.  Unger also romanizes 甲類 *i* as *i* and 乙類 *i* as *wi* to make that distinction.  So his rendering of *yopi* would imply 甲類 for *pi* here, and as such, 火 as an 乙類 would not be a likely candidate for reconstruction.

Comment: As a side note, an additional reason for why I find *yo pikari* to be an unlikely source for *yopi* is that, in my own poking around in etymologies, ancient Japanese roots all appear to be, at most, two syllables.  *Pikari* is the stem of verb *pikaru*, which itself might be decomposable as a compound of *pi* "sun, sunshine" + *karu* "to borrow".  Although Unger states that *OJ* pi *'sun, day' was not used for 'light'*,  the *Man'yōshū* uses 日 in ways that suggest that 日 was indeed used to mean 'sunlight, sunshine', c.f. poem #995.  My understanding is that the *Man'yōshū* counts as OJ.

Comment: Ran across this the other day, realized I'd used the wrong poem number.  Shogakukan's 国語大辞典 entry for 日{ひ} with a sense of "the sun's shining or heat; sunlight" gives a reference to [*Man'yōshū* poem #1995](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man10Yo.html#1995), not #995.  Click the link for the text.

Comment: One more for you -- doing further research into what this *hi* phoneme might be, I stumbled across an obsolete reading of *hi* (ancient *pi*) for 間: 『「ひま（隙）」の古形。』, with the etymology at 隙【ひま】 suggesting that the modern word *hima* is a compound of this ancient *hi* + *ma* (間). Shogakukan gives a quote from the [日本書紀【にほんしょき】](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihon_Shoki) using this reading and meaning, suggesting that this is a very old term.  This seems to be a much better semantic match as a possible etymon for 宵【よひ】: 夜【よ】 + 間【ひ】 = "night + period of time between two things".

Comment: The 日本書紀 is written in 漢文【かんぶん】, with the relevant term appearing in the line 『乘間得脱逃入其國。』 (source text [here on the Chinese Wikiquote](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%9B%B8%E7%B4%80/%E5%8D%B7%E7%AC%AC%E5%8D%81%E5%9B%9B)).  I did some googling as to how/why a 訓読【くんどく】 of *hi* would be used for the 間 character in the source text.  [This Chinese website that's a bit like Scribd](http://www.docin.com/p-348065274.html) has a PDF with some discussion of this, but going in an odd direction (that *hi* is mistaken).  Scroll down to the bottom of page 4, just under the red "P2015".

Comment: I can't find much online otherwise that explains why this instance of 間 in the 日本書紀 should be read as *hi*.