# Etymology of いい reading of 飯

Tags: etymology

I was surprised to learn that 飯 has the reading いい such as in 飯{いい}田{だ}橋{ばし}, and this is also [listed as an "archaicism"](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%A3%AF-2) in my dictionary. I know this kanji has the more usual kun-yomi めし (and on-yomi はん), but what is the etymology of this alternate reading? In particular, is it originally a native Japanese word (Yamato kotoba)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, い[ひ]{い} is indeed a yamato kotoba which can be found in [万葉集](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB). From [学研全訳古語辞典](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A3%AF):

> いひ 【飯】
>   名詞  飯（めし）。
>
> > 出典 万葉集　一四二
> >     「家にあれば笥（け）に盛るいひを」
> >     [訳] ⇒いへにあれば…。

いひ is even older than めし. めし gradually replaced いひ around the Muromachi period, according to [this page](http://gogen-allguide.com/me/meshi.html).

Comment: While I realize that you are quoting a dictionary, it is important to note that poem #142 does not actually contain any evidence that 飯 is supposed to be read as いひ. Rather, it contains the Chinese word 飯, but no 万葉仮名 to indicate how it is supposed to be read. It is certainly a reasonable guess considering that c. 11th century 類聚名義抄 contains the reading イヒモルケ (=飯盛る笥) which closely fits this context, but it is still a guess as well as being several centuries removed. Surely there are more definite textual sources that can be quoted.

Comment: [Poem 888](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man5Yos.html#888) uses phonetic 比{ひ} to spell the _-hi_ portion of 干{かれ}飯{ひ} _"dry rice, dry grain"_.  [Poem 3609S](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man15Yo.html#3609S) also uses 比{ひ} to spell 飯{ひ} phonetically in the compound 笥飯{けひ} (literally _"container grain"_), the ancient name of Tsuruga in Fukui Prefecture.

Answer (score 1):

### Origins of the *ii* reading

#### A native origin?

This appears as *ihi* in historical hiragana renderings (i.e. using kana spellings from before the Post-WWII spelling reforms), likely realized in ancient times as *ipi*.

Digging around, this is a bit of an odd one.  There are not many ancient native-Japanese words (*Yamato kotoba*) that have this phonetic structure.  `[VOWEL]` + `/pi/` could suggest a verbal derivation, but the only verb `/ipu/` is the root of modern 言{い}う, and that doesn't fit.

It could be a native term that's just a little odd.

#### An ancient nativized borrowing?

I have bumped into interesting suggestions that this might not be a *Yamato kotoba* after all.

The older meaning of 飯 with the `/ipi/` reading appears to be the more generic sense *"grain"*, rather than specifically *"rice"*.

We know from archaeology that the [Yayoi settlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yayoi_period) who crossed over to the Japanese archipelago from the mainland were also grain farmers.  The geographic origins are a bit murky, but be it modern Jiangsu Province or somewhere in Manchuria, these pre-Yayoi people would probably have had contact with Chinese speakers, and trade activities could lead to the borrowing of a few relevant words.

In Middle Chinese, 粒 *"grain"* was pronounced as `/liɪp̚/`, which we also see evidenced in now-obsolete Korean hanja reading [립]{rip}.  It seems that Old Japanese (and probably prehistoric Japanese) did not allow native words to begin with `/r/` (see quote and link in [this other JSE thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/etymology-of-%E5%AE%B5-%E3%82%88%E3%81%84#answer-15906)).  If Middle Chinese `/liɪp̚/` were imported into prehistoric Japanese, it may well have nativized as `/ipi/` rather than the `/ritu/` form we see for the later borrowing of 立 with a similar MK reading of `/liɪp̚/`.

And given the nearly-millenia-long Japanese propensity for applying kanji spellings in creative ways to write words with related meanings but different readings, it is not much of a stretch to find the 飯 character with a Chinese meaning of *"food, cooked rice"* used for the `/ipi/` *"grain"* sense.

Note that this is all **very** circumstantial.

### Side note: Origins of the *meshi* reading

It bears noting that the *kun'yomi* of めし is the 連用形{れんようけい} or continuative form of verb 召{め}す.  This started out as an honorific for 見{み}る, using the *-e* vowel stem + ancient honorific verb ending す (which interestingly has parallels with the *-si-* or *-se-* honorific verb infix in Korean).  Over time, and through various evolutions of usage and meaning, this verb *mesu* gained a sense of *"to put into or onto the body"* → *"to eat; to drink; to wear"*.  The *"eat"* sense is already apparent in the [*Man'yōshū*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB) in [poem 3853](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man16Yo.html#3853), which spells out the imperative form 召{め}せ in phonetic [*man'yōgana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dgana) as 賣{め}世{せ}.