# If 'little girl' is 「少女」, then why is 'little boy' 「少年」?

Tags: words, kanji

#### Question

少女 means `little girl` because 少 means `little/small` and 女 means `lady/female`. It makes sense here. However it does not make sense when I read 少年 because 年 means `year`. **Is there any reason why 年 was used instead of 男 which means `men/male`?**

#### Research

My stackexchange search skills are poor, and my [search](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4) [attempts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%B0%91%E5%A5%B3) did not yield anything relevant to my question. Googling something however gave me [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dnen).

It said:

> Shōnen (少年?), shonen, or shounen, is a kango word that literally means few years and generally refers to a typical boy from elementary school through high school age. It is used in everyday conversation when referring to the period of youth, including in legal wording referencing youth, without regard to gender.

So if my understanding is correct 少年 means young person regardless of gender (because `small years` or `few years` [of living] means the person is still young).

However, this does not answer my question as to why the counterpart of 少女 is 少年 and not 少男.

Some expert opinion on this would be appreciated because the Wikipedia article I quoted has the superscript `clarification needed`.

Comment: Given that you read the wiki page you quoted, I don't really understand your concern. Isn't it natural that in most languages grammatical gender is highly asymmetrical and a masculine form is used to indicate a general meaning? Going from the other way round: would an English reader understand that the California Child Actor's Bill (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Child_Actor%27s_Bill) pertains only to boys? And wonder why isn't it called "California Child Actor's and Actress' Bill" or would he (sic!) take it for granted?

Comment: Just my two cent, the term 少年 is most often heard when it refers to young criminals, who tend to be male.

Comment: @macraf I get your point. In general, the masculine form is used. Maybe my question is confusing (I will try to rephrase) but what I really want to know is why was the kanji 年 used instead of 男.

Comment: @Keale Why is Dutch "Meer" called "See" in German and Dutch "Zee" is called "Meer" in German? Because languages evolve and when a need appears to make a distinction from more general term (something like "body of water" here) a new word is created. Probably the same way 少年 was used for young person regardless of age (like in law today) and then a need to make a distinction between sexes arose. 少女 was most likely devised in the same way as (political correctness aside) like "actress" is linguistically a subset of "actor".

Comment: @macraf Err... I think your comment right there will be more suited as an answer I guess? I actually kinda got enlightened by your first comment so I'm now creating an answer myself, but please feel free to answer.

Comment: There are more pairs of words with a similar relationship: 姫(ひ-め, 日-女)　and 彦(ひ-こ, 日-子) [=女子・男子の美称]; and the pair 乙女(おと-め) and 男(おと-こ, おと-子) [=年の若い女性・男性]; and the pair 娘(むす-め, 生す-女) and 息子(むす-こ, 生す-子). Interestingly, 子 is sometimes used to refer to (young) girls these days...

Comment: Wow, never knew the etymology of any of those, fascinating! (Do you have a favorite source for stuff like that?)

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Not one source, but the bigger Japanese monolingual dictionaries often give some etymology for the words they list (but take with a grain of salt, sometimes they include speculation). Sometimes I come across a word and wonder where they come from, and I look it up. There's also an online dictionary for this, [gogen-allguide](http://gogen-allguide.com).

Comment: The list in [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/kanji-for-native-japanese-concepts-kunyomi-spanning-multiple-morphemes)  might be of interest as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Im no expert in Japanese but [macraf](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/11104/macraf)'s comment somehow enlightened me to an answer.

In English, we have nouns like god, actor, waiter etc. These nouns do not necessarily denote a gender because they are **supersets**.
Their subsets are: god & goddess for god, actor & actress for actor and waiter and waitress for waiter.

Visually it's like:

```
  god            actor            waiter
  / \             / \              / \
god goddess   actor actress   waiter waitress
```

As you can see, the superset is also the word for the male, and the one for the female is another word.

So in the case of the question, 少年 is the superset for young people. Following the above example, it will also be the word for the male, and the word for the female is another word, 少女.

```
  少年
  /  |
少年 少女
```

Comment: @Ninj0r Can 兄妹 mean "brothers"? I thought it was 兄弟 that's ambiguous between "brothers" and "siblings", while 兄妹 was specifically a brother and a sister, the former being older.

Comment: yes. I agree. All of this is called "markedness". In this case, "少女" is the marked term. In English, we do the same thing such as marking "lioness".

Comment: @shenshin Sorry, typo; thanks for catching; you are correct. 

Re-posting: `兄弟` and `姉妹` is another set that follows this pattern; `兄弟` can mean "siblings" or "brothers" but `姉妹` is always "sisters"

Comment: The other way round example: 美人{びじん} is used only for women, while more specific 美男子{びだんし} is be used for men.

Comment: By the way, we very very very rarely use 少年 to mean a "little girl". It sounds kind of archaic.