# Etymology of 姪 and 甥

Tags: etymology, nouns, kinship-terms

姪 "niece" is often pronounced [[me.i]] rather than [[meː]] (see e.g. [this comment in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24426515#24426515)). I think the reason for this is that there is a morpheme boundary in 姪, presumably

> 姪 = 女【め】 + イ = female イ

Unfortunately, 姪 is not listed in any of the answers in the question "[Kanji for native Japanese concepts: Kun'yomi spanning multiple morphemes](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6581/1628)" (or it might be hidden in another word and I haven't noticed).

What is the meaning of イ and what is the etymology of 姪 and 甥?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shogakukan's 大国語辞典 shows that 姪【めい】 has a historical hiragana spelling of めひ, not めい, showing that the modern *mei* reading is not *on'yomi* but rather *kun'yomi*.  This different derivation is probably also why the pronunciation is different: `[mei]` with a more distinct `[i]`, and not `[meː]`.  The term for "nephew", 甥【おい】, has a historical hiragana spelling of をひ.  As you note, め is an old morpheme indicating "female", and を is an old morpheme indicating "male".  We now have a clear follow-on morpheme ひ.

This ひ is of uncertain derivation.  The closest vaguely relevant match that I can currently find is prefix 曾【ひ】, often glossed as "great" in terms like 曾【ひ】お祖母【ばあ】さん "great-grandmother", 曾【ひ】孫【まご】 "great-grandchild", etc.  Shogakukan's given definition for 曾【ひ】 is:

> 血縁関係を表す語について、それよりさらに一代離れた関係にあることを示す。
>     For terms expressing a blood relation, this indicates a relation separated by one more generation.

I wonder if there might have been an older meaning, still referring to relative distance from oneself, but not necessarily of a different generation; and an older usage, not as a prefix but as a noun.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: @broccoliforest also [mentioned](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24430652#24430652) 彦{ひこ} and 姫{ひめ} in chat. (Also, welcome back, yeay!)

Comment: It's worth noting that Shogakukan's *Kokugo Dai Jiten* entries for 彦【ひこ】 and 姫【ひめ】 describe the prefix ひ as cognate with 日 and functioning as an honorific prefix.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie -- The relevant entries (the SE comment feature seems to delete linebreaks, so imagine that the \\ are linebreaks): 

ひこ【彦】  \\

（「日子」の意）  \\

----  \\

ひ【日】  \\

...  \\

7　皇室や皇族に関する事柄につけて、ほめたたえる気持を表す語。日の神、すなわち、天照大神の子孫の意とも、光り輝く太陽にたとえたことばともいう。「日の御子」「日の御門」など。