# Difference between 意志｛いし｝ and 志し｛こころざし｝ (will)

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

I learnt both 意志{いし} and 志し{こころざし}, but am always confusing the two of them.

Can someone highlight the differences between those 2 words (and other variants if any) ?

Comment: Related: [Origin/etymology of こころ～ words](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1400/78).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 意志{いし}

It's just the **will** or **desire** of doing anything. **やろう**とする気持{きも}ち。

- 今週中{こんしゅうちゅう}にそのプロジェクトをやり遂げるという意志がある。

> 志{こころざし}

Including the meaning of 意志{いし}, it's the **determination** or **resolution** to carry out a higher, long term goal or objective. It's not just the will, but the **ambition**, **aspiration** and **resolve** to do something.

- 志{こころざし}は高{たか}く持{もつ}つべきだ。
- 将来{しょうらい}博士{はかせ}になるという志{こころざし}を持{も}つ。

志{こころざし} is mostly used in the written language, as opposed to 意志, not uncommon  in spoken conversation at all.

A variant could be [意向{いこう}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E6%84%8F%E5%90%91?catId=business) used in business contexts to mean intention or [つもり](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A).

Comment: Looks good to me, accepting. Not sure why it got downvotes though

Comment: Looks basically OK to me, too, but the noun 志し is the 連用形 of verb 志す. Its noun form is usually written as 志【こころざし】 without し (similar to 話【はな】し (連用形) and 話【はなし】 (story)).

Comment: Edited. You are right.